# Newer/smaller laptops are giving "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" message

Tags: networking, wireless, realtek-wireless, wifi-hardware-switch

I have one older 15-inch laptop (HP Notebook) and two newer 14-inch laptops (Lenovo Ideapad and HP Pavilion). The same thing is happening when I use Ubuntu on the two newer ones, but not on the older one.

There's no wifi icon, and when I go to the wifi settings I get this message: "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found. Make sure you have a Wi-Fi adapter plugged and turned on".

I actually installed Ubuntu on the Lenovo, but I only chose the "try Ubuntu" option with the other two. I tried it with the two most recent versions, `18.04.2 LTS` and `19.04`, with the same effect.

I'm surprised that this problem seems rare, as I couldn't find anything very helpful online. [This](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2399442) seems the closest to my problem, and it suggests reinstalling a kernel, but without internet, I'm obviously getting network errors in my terminal. The two problematic computers unfortunately don't have ethernet ports either, so I have no idea what to do..

Here's the output to `sudo lshw -class network` (hopefully it's the relevant wireless card info):

> *-network UNCLAIMED
>   description: Network controller
>   product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
>   Vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
>   physical id: 0
>   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
>   version: 00
>   width: 64 bits
>   clock: 33 MHz
>   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
>   configuration: latency=0
>   resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0700000-c070ffff

---

**Output of "lspci -v"**:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b822
  Subsystem: Lenovo Device b023
  Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
  I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
  Memory at c0700000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
  Capabilities: <access denied>
  Kernel modules: r8822be
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of hardware doesn't work if you don't have the firmware installed. Have you tried pulling in firmware-linux-nonfree?

Also, could you give us the output of 'lspci -v'?  This should give us the model, hopefully.

Comment: Is that a package? Unfortunately I apparently can't pull anything from the internet. I appended the network controller output of 'lspci -v' to the question.